# Is this integral incomplete gamma function?

Tags: gamma-function

I'm trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{x} t^{s-1}e^t dt$$
where, $0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq t \leq 1, s >0$. Although I know the following integral is an incomplete gamma function
$$\gamma(s, x) = \int_{0}^{x} t^{s-1}e^{-t} dt$$
Can someone please explain me if we can solve the other integral?

Comment: Is $s$ an integer or anything ?

Comment: Right now $s \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$. But how does $s$ being an integer will help in evaluating that integral?

Comment: If $s$ is an integer, as @Marty Cohen answered, we can build an easy recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "solve"?

The first integral diverges as
$x \to \infty$ and the second converges.

Both can be computed by putting in the power series for
$e^t$ and integrating term by term.
The first integral behaves better computationally
since all the terms are positive
so there is no cancellation.

You can get  increasingly accurate estimates
of the first integral
by repeated integration by parts,
just as for the second.

Comment: I realized that the previous post was not clear and so I edited the post. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Make $t=-u$
$$I=\int_{0}^{x} t^{s-1}e^t dt=-\int_{0}^{-x}e^{-u} (-u)^{s-1}\,du=(-1)^{-s} (\Gamma (s)-\Gamma (s,-x))$$

Comment: Since, $\Gamma(s) - \Gamma(s, -x) = \gamma(s, -x)$, am I right in saying that the above integral is a lower incomplete gamma function (of course with $(-1)^-s$ factor)?